# java StringTokenizer unexpected results

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

i have the following code which will tokenize the string to create list of Objects:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class TestStringTokenizer {
    private final static String INTERNAL_DELIMETER = "#,#";
    private final static String EXTERNAL_DELIMETER = "#|#";
    public static void main(String[]aregs){
        String test= "1#,#Jon#,#176#|#2#,#Jack#,#200#|#3#,#Jimmy#,#160";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test, EXTERNAL_DELIMETER);
        while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement());
            //later will take this token and extract elements
        }
    }
}
```

**What i expected output was** 
1#,#Jon#,#176 
2#,#Jack#,#200
3#,#Jimmy#,#160

**What i got was** :
1
,
Jon
,
176
2
,
Jack
,
200
3
,
Jimmy
,
160

if i change the internal delimeter to some thing like *,* it will work properly
why is this behavior happening ?

Comment: `StringTokenizer` doesn't take `#|#` as one single delimiter, but as 3 delimiters. Kindly go through the API of that class to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StrinTokenizer constructor's second parameter is delimiters(Each character is a delimiter)

You can use String.split instead

```
public class TestStringTokenizer {
    private final static String INTERNAL_DELIMETER = "#,#";
    private final static String EXTERNAL_DELIMETER = "#|#";
    public static void main(String[]aregs){
        String test= "1#,#Jon#,#176#|#2#,#Jack#,#200#|#3#,#Jimmy#,#160";
        for (String s : test.split("#\\|#"))
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am surprised that split only runs once, being in the foreach loop like that. I honestly wouldn't put it there even if it does work. Confusing.

Comment: its not giving the correct o/p as expected .... I have edited the code...now it works

Comment: I added an escape character before | since the split parameter is a regex

Comment: The iterator part of the for-each loop is evaluated once to get an iterator

Comment: There are two problems with your code, but they're not really bugs, per se: `INTERNAL_DELIMETER` is not used at all in your answer, so consider eliminating it. `EXTERNAL_DELIMITER` is also not being used, but it *should* be. Instead of calling split with the *value* of `EXTERNAL_DELIMITER`, call it with the variable-name (and change the value of `EXTERNAL_DELIMITER` so its or-pipe is escaped). As it stands, this answer is *correct*, but written very confusingly. I'll delete this comment once it's fixed. Just respond with @aliteralmind.

Answer (score 5):

AccordIng to the StringTokenizer JavaDocs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Use String.split instead:

```
String[] strArr = stringToSplit.split(INTERNAL_DELIMETER);
```

The only change you need to make is that the or-pipe ("|") in EXTERNAL_DELIMETER is a special regular expression character, and must be escaped: "\\|".

More information can be found in the String.split Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

StrinTokenizer can't work with expression as a delimiter, try Scanner instead

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(test);
    sc.useDelimiter("#\\|#");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```